# Use external array inside class PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, class

I have this function (in file functions.php) that returns me a list of the users in a database.

```
function db_listar_usuarios(){
    $link = db_connect();
    $query = "select * from usuarios" or die("Problemas en el select: " . mysqli_error($link));
    $result = $link->query($query);
    $myArray = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {   
        $myArray[$row['nombre']] = $row;
        //print_r($myArray); // for debugging
    }
    return $myArray;
    //print_r($myArray);
}
```

and i want to use it in a Class that is in another file (server.php)

```
<?php
include('functions.php');

class Server {    
    private $contacts = db_listar_usuarios(); //<-- this doesn't work =(
...
}
```

What can I do to make this code work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call a function in that position.  When you declare class variables, they must be constants (see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

You need to use the constructor to do that.

```
<?php
include('functions.php');

class Server {    
    private $contacts;

    function __construct(){
        $this->contacts = db_listar_usuarios();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Excellent response!

Comment: Glad I could help! :-D

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not allow to set dynamic values in the property declaration. You cannot call a function in that place.

You have to move that function call to the constructor, which is called automatically when an instance of that class is created:

```
private $contacts;

public function __construct() {
    $this->contacts = db_listar_usuarios();
}
```